# Refreshing caller listpage form

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I need to call parent form but my parent form is a listpage form. 
As I know I can't add new methods to list page forms i need to add this method to the interaction class of related list page form. But I do not have an idea how to do it.

Would you have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Set the `AutoRefreshData` on the menu item on the list page. This will refresh the list page, I am not sure when (maybe it works best on action menu items).
2. Call `element.args().record().datasource().research(true);` from the child form.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh a datasource of a calling record. 
You need to cast element.args().record().datasource() to FormDatasource so you can call research() or executeQuery() depending of you needs.
Also you can/must check if record is from a form by using method on common isFormDatasource(). If this is true than this record is from form. 
If you need to refresh parent from another form you should do it in closeOk() method of this form or at the end of you logic in a class.

Comment: thanks Anze, i have missed the point about closeOk(),refactored my code to use it as well.